# Is it possible to process and move lines of text matching a pattern to another location matching another pattern (in the same file)?

Tags: perl, awk, text, sed, replace

I need to process and move some blocks of text in a file (stream, actually).

The procedure is not trivial, but conceptually quite simple, so I was wondering what's the simplest way to perform it via text processing tools.

Sample input follows; the dashes are irrelevant text:

```
---
---
FOO 1,
FOO 2
---
---
BAR 0 --
---
---
```

which should become:

```
---
---
---
---
-- BAR 0 BAZ FOO 1,
BAZ FOO 2
--
---
---
```

The whitespace (type) in the destination is irrelevant, as long as there is some spacing, so, if it's simpler, a target line like this works as well:

```
-- BAR 0 BAZ FOO 1, BAZ FOO 2--
```

Probably, sed's hold buffer or Perl variables would do, but I don't know them good enough to pull something simple (if possible).

Comment: It is exceedingly unclear from your example what your criteria are for extracting and re-arranging text.

Comment: We can't even tell from that example if you're trying to replace FOO 1 and FOO 2 individually or only when they occur as a pair of contiguous lines. The text represented by the dashes is never irrelevant when doing text matching btw - you should replace that with some truly representative text.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/FOO/H;//d;/BAR/!b;x;s/\n/ BAZ /g;H;z;x;s/\n//g;s/, /,\n/g;s/-- //g;s/.*/-- &\n--/' file
```

Copy the `FOO` lines into the hold space and append and manipulate them into the desired format on finding a `BAR` line.

Alternative format:

```
sed '/FOO/H;//d;/BAR/!b;x;s/\n/ BAZ /g;H;z;x;s/ --\n//;s/.*/-- & --/' file
```

N.B. This is destructive and depends on `BAR` following `FOO`. Another approach is needed where this is unconditional perhaps using the `/FOO/{:a;N;/^BAR/M!ba;....}' file` idiom.